# List Items + Fields In Datasource

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to setup an email notification and my hope is to have a simple list of all the items in a datasource (separated into their fields).

Ex:

ItemName01, Cost01, Quantity01

ItemName02, Cost02, Quantity02

ItemName03, Cost03, Quantity03

Doing a projection of each (@datasources.Datasource.items..ItemName + @datasources.Datasource.items..Cost + @datasources.Datasource.items..Quantity) gives me everything, but not organized correctly.

Ex. [ItemName01,ItemName02,ItemName03],[Cost01,Cost02,Cost03],[Quantity01,Quantity02,Quantity03]

Any help/thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use server script for this:

```js
// query records
var records = app.models.Item.newQuery().run();

// generate email HTML body
var emailBody = records.reduce(function(str, item) {
  str += '<p>' + item.Name + ', ' + item.Cost + ', ' + item.Quantity + '</p>'
});

// hand off generated HTML to other function
// that will actually send email
sendEmail(emailBody);
```

You can call this Server Script from Model Events or explicitly from client using `google.script.run`. You also can pass some filters to narrow records set to be sent.